# Angular 15 - Routing Module Issue

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular14, angular15

I updated to Anglar 15 and I'm having a problem with the redirect, according to what the error says, I have a double //, but the reality is that I don't have anything like that in my code.

## **

## PagesRoutingModule:**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    redirectTo: "dashboard",
    pathMatch: "full",
  },
  {
    path: '/',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages.module').then(module => module.PagesModule)
  },
```

## **

## AppRoutingModule**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: "pages",
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () => import('./login-page/login-page.module').then(module => module.LoginPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'pages',
    canLoad: [AuthGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/pages.module').then(module => module.PagesModule),
  },
```

I also tried removing the '/' from path inside my PagesRoutingModule, but this loops my application.

Comment: What is the exact error you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: https://prnt.sc/1X6tk3NVC505]

you are again loading  pagemodule in page routing module.